# How to add reCaptcha to Firefox add-on?

Tags: firefox-addon, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I know that adding Google's reCaptcha to Chrome extension requires addition of chrome extension id to the allowed-list on reCaptcha. That works. But what is the alternative way to use Google capthcha in a Firefox add-on.

As far as I know, the internal UUID of Firefox add-on changes every time you re-install the add-on. The external id can be made fixed but it is not used in the add-on urls. Is there a way around this problem?